# Fedora 29 Virtualbox - Had Guest Additions 6.0.6 - tried to upgrade to 6.0.8 and now cannot mount it (unknown filesystem type 'iso9660')

Tags: fedora, mount, virtualbox

Host machine is Win10 if it matters.

I did not realize Guest Additions for Virtualbox was already installed on my Fedora 29 VM.

I used device -> "Insert Guest Additions CD Image", then mounted it. It ran, removed the old one, mentioned some kind of error and then finished.

Now, after a reboot, it appears guest additions is gone. I tried doing the same steps, but now when I try, I cannot mount the guest additions:

"Error mounting dev/sr0 at /run/media/myname/Vbox_GAs_6.0.8: unknown filesystem type 'iso9660'"

I took `yum`, and `update`'d, `upgrade`'d and `autoremove`'d. I was already up-to-date.

I used the techniques [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/169024/how-can-i-tell-if-the-virtualbox-guest-additions-were-installed-on-an-ubuntu-vm) to confirm it is no longer installed, but it's fairly clear given the screen is different now.

Every time I find threads on this topic, they mention that their issue is being unable to eject the ISO, which I can easily do. (I've ejected it and re-added it half a dozen times trying to get it to mount)

A reboot has not helped either, I tried a few times.

Any recommendations?

Comment: Don't you want to run [VirtualBox 6.0.14](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) now?  From your Fedora 29 guest, have you tried [`dnf install virtualbox-guest-additions`](https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/virtualbox-guest-additions#) and then reboot?

Comment: I did try using DFA. My virtualbox is slightly out of date, I'll try updating it if I can.